# Android: Handling json objects that can be a string or array

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

Ran into a situation where am not sure how to handle it.

I have json data that comes from a server; for example:(am just posting part of the json, so, yes, the json is valid)

```
    "wall_id": 889149,
    "poster_image_thumbnail": "http:\/\/www.mface.me\/images\/avatar\/thumb_62441559ddb1dda7513d0f94.jpg",
    "post_type": "profile",
    "post_content": [{
        "text": "",
        "images_count": 1,
        "images": ["https:\/\/fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-ash4\/227408_475848819113499_663318592_n.jpg"]
    }]
```

Created a class to store this json data

```
public class feedFormat{
    Integer wall_id;
    String poster_image_thumbnail;
    String post_type;
    String post_content;
}
```

There are times when **post_content** can be empty or an array as the example above. I have declared post_content as String in feedFormat. This is obviously throwing a **cast exception** (Converting array to string?).

I was expecting JSONObject to read it as a string and later convert it into an array from there, but does'nt seem to go that way.

How can i dynamically handle a **string or an array**?  if it is an array, i need to break it down.

I am porting this app from IOS to android, there is a "id" object in IOS that can be of any class. I check if the class is a NSSTring or NSArray and take it from there. Here in Java, am not sure how to handle it.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated

Comment: I say use Array, and in case of an empty string put an empty array there instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your JSON array is empty, it will be like that :

```
"post_content": []
```

It will then remain an array, with the particularity of being 0-sized.

Then I suggest you parse directly your JSON array into a appropriate data structure, whatever the size, like an ArrayList> for example. You will then be able to go through all the items of your JSON array, and for each item, add a new HashMap in your arraylist. Every hashmap will contain there pairs of key values.

However, if I understand well your JSON, it seems that it will be always an array of three elements, the third element being itself a array, which size is given bu the attribute images_count. This is not very good, your JSON structure should be :

```
"post_content": {
    "text": "",
    "images": [
        "https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/227408_475848819113499_663318592_n.jpg"
    ]
}
```

Since images is an array, you can easily get its size.

Comment: Thanks Raphael
But, at this point i cant change the way post_content comes, it will still be "" - i cant change it because it is already being used by my iphone app.

Comment: I understand that you can not change it. In this case, I suggest that in your Android app, you first check if postContent is a JSONArray. If so, parse it the way I indicate : Use an arrayList<HashMap>. However, if you are sure that postContent never contains more than 1 element, you can directly store "text" in a String and cast "images_count" to a integer, and then use an ArrayList<String> for every element of the "images" array. Hope this helps !

Comment: Am sorry for my ignorance, am a little lost here. I have tried to check if the post_content is array with if (currentRecord.get("post_content") instanceof JSONArray) - which shows true when post_content is array, but i cant seem to break down the array, editing my question now

Comment: Your array indeed contains one object only. As you can see, the [], which delimit the array,contain one pair or {}, which delimits your object. Your object however contains 3 elements. Using an array which is always of size 1 is not the right way to do it, that's why I mentionned earlier that your JSON should be adapted to a JSON object, containing one String and one JSON Array elements. TO understand well the JSON syntax, I recommand you to have a look at this link : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example

Comment: hey Raphael, yeah i figured that out a few minutes ago. That was purely my mistake and thanks for the reply too. i guess i just need a break for my brain; i have been on a coding marathon and i am missing on simple errors.

Answer (score 0):

`JSONObject` has functions called `has(String key)` which checks if there is a mapping for a key and `isNull(String key)` which checks if a particular key is `null`. Use these to check the key before reading.

Comment: Use @raphael-titol 's answer if your post_content is giving an empty array instead of null.

Answer (score 0):

you can check like this `jsonobject.has("post_content")`

```
if(jsonobject.has("post_content")) {
   /// read array and do remaining stuff
}else {
  // if not read another strings and put post_content as null.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FeedFormat{
    Integer wall_id;
    String poster_image_thumbnail;
    String post_type;
    JSONArray post_content;
}

feedFormat toto = new feedFormat();
toto.post_content = yourJsonObject.getJsonArray("post_content");
```

This is the easiest way to do what you want. Another way is to create another class.

```
public class FeedFormat{
    Integer wall_id;
    String poster_image_thumbnail;
    String post_type;
    ArrayList<PostContent> post_content = new ArrayList<PostContent>();
}

public class PostContent {
    String text;
    Integer imageCount;
    ArrayList<String> images = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

With that you can handle each post content into specific object instead of use JSONObject / JSONArray.

Comment: Thanks Cyril, will this work if content is empty? I will give it a shot and see.

Comment: If content is empty it will work but before use your data (you want to retrieve all post_content's text for example) check if `post_content` is empty: `.lenght()` methode for JSONArray or ArrayList do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
String data= "wall_id": 889149,
"poster_image_thumbnail": "http:\/\/www.mface.me\/images\/avatar\/thumb_62441559ddb1dda7513d0f94.jpg",
"post_type": "profile",
"post_content": [{
    "text": "",
    "images_count": 1,
    "images": ["https:\/\/fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-ash4\/227408_475848819113499_663318592_n.jpg"]
}]

JSONArray jArray=data.getJSONArray("post_content");
for(int i=0; i<jArray.length(); i++)
{
JSONObject jObj=jArray.getJSONObject(i);
String text=jObj.getString("text");
int images_count=jObj.getInt("images_count");
String images=jObj.getInt("images");
}
```

Comment: WIll this not raise a class cast exception when post_content is empty?